# Having Issue on Receiving Emails From @Gmail.com or @Yahoo. in WordPress Using PHP Mail Function

Tags: email

Using WordPress 4.0.1 and PHP Mail Function I am not getting Emails from Gmail and Yahoo Users. I am getting Emails from private domains like Test@Test.com but nothing if the email ends up by yahoo or gmail( or maybe other domains like hotmail). I am not getting any error message either but no mail receiving!

Here is the code I am using

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    } 
    $to_Email       = "something@gmail.com";
    $subject        = 'Contact For Rumi Optical Web Customer'; 
    if(!isset($_POST["name"]) || !isset($_POST["email"]) || !isset($_POST["subject"]) || !isset($_POST["message"]))
    {
        die();
    }

    $user_Name          = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email         = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone         = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Message       = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) 
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Name is too short or empty!');
        exit();
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Please enter a valid email!');
        exit();
    }
    if(strlen($user_Phone)<4) 
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Only numbers allowed in phone field');
        exit();
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) 
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Too short message! Please enter something.');
        exit();
    }

    $headers = "From: " .$user_Email. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_Email. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . $user_Name  . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $user_Email . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Subject:</strong> </td><td>" . $user_Phone  . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" . $user_Message . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";


    @$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $message , $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Could not send mail! Sorry..');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Hi '.$user_Name .', Thank You for Your Message! <br />';
        echo 'We Have Received Your Message and Will Contact You ASAP.</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your spam filter? Have you tested if the mails are not sent or just not received? This could help as well: http://mailcatcher.me/

Comment: Yes I did, I am not getting them any where ! not in inbox neither in Spam or junk box!

Comment: Can someone please give me an idea why this is happening?

Comment: I am 99% sure that if only some mails do not get through this is some kind of spam-filter issue. Have you tried using a local copy of the site in combination with http://mailcatcher.me/ to check if the mails are just not received or also never leaving the server?